# como ordenar las clinicas por distancia?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Estoy desarrollando un localizador con react google map api, obtengo un listado de clínicas y una operacion matematica que me devuelve la distancia entre las clínicas y la posición del usuario, estoy tratando de ordenar la lista de clínicas empezando por la mas cercana a la mas lejana, pero recibo errores al querer usar el método sort para ordenar la lista, estoy trabajando con typescript y por el momento no se mucho.E puesto la parte del codigo donde se calcula las distancias y donde intento hacer el sort y el error que me da es el siguiente Property 'sort' does not exist on type 'number'.

```
function getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2) {
        var R = 6371; // radio de la tierraa km
        var dLat = deg2rad(lat2-lat1);  // deg2rad 
        var dLon = deg2rad(lon2-lon1); 
        var a = 
          Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
          Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * 
          Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2)
          ; 
        var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
        var d = R * c; // Distancia en km
       
        return d;
       
      }

      function deg2rad(deg) {
        return deg * (Math.PI/180)
        
      }

  <div className="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 gap-4">
                                                <div className="w-100 h-40 md:h-96">
                                                 { isLoaded  && (
                                                    <GoogleMap
                                                        zoom={15}
                                                        mapContainerStyle={containerStyle}
                                                        center={center}
                                                        onLoad={onLoad}
                                                        onUnmount={onUnmount}
                                                          >
                                                    {console.log('center',center)}
                                                        <MarkerF position={{lat:currentLatitude, lng:currentLongitude}} />

                                                        {clinicListFiltered.map((clinic) => (
                                                            <React.Fragment key={clinic.id}>
                                                                <MarkerF  position={{ lat: clinic.latitude ? clinic.latitude : -1, lng: clinic.longitude ? clinic.longitude : -1 }} onClick={() => handleActiveMarker(clinic.id)} options={{ icon: iconclinic }}>
                                                                    {activeMarker === clinic.id ? (
                                                                        <InfoWindow
                                                                            position={{ lat: clinic.latitude ? clinic.latitude : -1, lng: clinic.longitude ? clinic.longitude : -1 }}
                                                                            onCloseClick={() => setActiveMarker(null)}
                                                                            >
                                                                            <div style={divStyle}>
                                                                                <h1>{clinic.title}</h1>
                                                                                <p>{clinic.address}</p>
                                                                                <p>{clinic.phone}</p>
                                                                                <p>{clinic.email}</p>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </InfoWindow>
                                                                    ) : null}
                                                                </MarkerF>
                                                            </React.Fragment>
                                                            
                                                        ))}
                                                         {direction && (
                                                        <MarkerF position={direction} />
                                                         )}
                                                    </GoogleMap>
                                                 )}
                                                </div>
                                                <div className="overflow-auto max-h-96">
                                                    
                                                    {
                                                        clinicListFiltered.map((clinic) => (
                                                            <>
                                                            <div key={clinic.id} className="card bg-white px-2 py-3 h-62 md:h-50 mb-3">
                                                                <button  type="button" className="text-left">
                                                                
                                                                    {!direction ?
                                                                         <p>{getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(currentLatitude,currentLongitude,clinic.latitude,clinic.longitude).sort().toFixed()}Km</p>
                                                                        : 
                                                                         <p>{getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(direction.lat,direction.lng,clinic.latitude,clinic.longitude).sort().toFixed()} Km</p>  
                                                                        
                                                                    }

                                                                     {/* {console.log.sort(getDistanceFromLatLonInKm([currentLatitude],[currentLongitude],[clinic.latitude,clinic.longitude)).sort(compareMarker(a,b))} */}
                                                                 
                                                                    <div className="flex items-center gap-2 md:gap-4 md:gap-4">
                                                                        
                                                                        <img className="h-24 w-2/5 min-w-40 object-container object-center rounded-lg" src={contentUtils.getLargeImageUrl(clinic.logo)} alt="#" />
                                                                        <div className="w-3/5">
                                                                            <div className="text-md font-medium leading-5 clinic-title uppercase">{clinic.title}</div>
                                                                            <div className="flex items-center gap-2">
                                                                                <div className="text-neutral-500 text-sm">{clinic.propsPhone}</div>
                                                                                <div className="text-neutral-500 text-sm">{clinic.mobile}</div>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                            <div className="text-teal-600 text-sm underline clinic-mail">{clinic.email}</div>
                                                                            <div className="text-neutral-500 text-sm">{clinic.registry}</div>
                                                                            <div className="text-teal-600 text-sm underline clinic-mail">{clinic.email}</div>
                                                                            <div className="text-neutral-500 text-xs">{getType(clinic.type)}</div>
                                                                            <div className="text-neutral-500 text-xs">{getPhysiotherapyFields(clinic.physiotherapyFields)}</div> 
                                                                            <div className="text-neutral-500 text-xs">{getOthers(clinic.others)}</div> 
                                                                            <div className="text-neutral-500 text-xs">{getFeatureFilters(clinic.featureFilterList)}</div> 
                                                                            <div className="text-neutral-500 text-sm">{clinic.registry}</div>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </button>
                                                            </div>
                                                           
                                                              </>
                                                        ))
                                                    }
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

Comment: El error te lo da porque .sort es una función para ordenar arrays y el método getDistanceFromLatLonInKm devuelve un number.

Comment: y que solución hay?

Comment: Porque no pre-procesar `clinicListFiltered` para que devuelva el arreglo ordenado por distancia antes de hacer el render, parece que estas tratando de hacer el sort en render time y hay variables que se toman desde afuera de `clinicListFiltered`, por ejemplo `currentLatitude,currentLongitude` parece que estan en el outter scope,  `separation of concerns` puede ser de ayuda aquí.