# como ordenar las clinicas por distancia mas cercana?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Estoy desarrollando un localizador con react google map api, obtengo un listado de clínicas y una operación matemática que me devuelve la distancia entre las clínicas y la posición del usuario, estoy tratando de ordenar la lista de clínicas empezando por la mas cercana a la mas lejana, estoy usando una función para ordenarlas antes de mapear los resultados pero voy un poco perdido.No se si la función es correcta ni donde llamarla exactamente, se que es un poco complejo pero dejo el código por si alguien me puede sugerir como hacerlo.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useMemo, useCallback, useRef } from 'react'
import { getClinic } from '../../api/drupalAPI'
import { Clinic, CollectionItem } from '@icofcv/common';
import { getClinicCollections } from '../../api/icofcvAPI';
import contentUtils from '../../lib/contentUtils'
import Loader from '../spinner/Loader';
import { GoogleMap, useJsApiLoader, MarkerF, MarkerClusterer, InfoWindow } from '@react-google-maps/api';
import PlacesAutocomplete, {
    geocodeByAddress,
    getLatLng
} from "react-places-autocomplete";
import iconclinic from '../../assets/images/iconclinic.png'
import Places from "./Places";
import { useGeolocation, getDistanceFromLatLonInKm, getDistanceFromLatLonInMiles } from 'cadmv-use-geolocation'
// import { MarkerClusterer } from "@googlemaps/markerclusterer";


interface Props {
    showModalLocator: boolean,
    closeModalLocator: () => void
}
type LatLngLiteral = google.maps.LatLngLiteral;

export const ClinicLocator: React.FC<Props> = ({ children, showModalLocator, closeModalLocator }) => {

    const [clinicList, setClinicList] = useState<Clinic[]>([]);
    const [clinicListFiltered, setClinicListFiltered] = useState<Clinic[]>([]);
    

    const [currentLatitude, setCurrentLatitude] = useState(Number)
    const [currentLongitude, setCurrentLongitude] = useState(Number)
 

    const [direction, setDirection] = useState<LatLngLiteral>();
    const mapRef = useRef<GoogleMap>();


    const fetchClinics = async () => {
        //setIsLoading(true)
        getClinic()
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response)
                setClinicList(response);
                setClinicListFiltered(response)
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
                throw error;
            });
    }

    ////cargar mapa

    const { isLoaded } = useJsApiLoader({
        id: 'google-map-script',
        googleMapsApiKey: "AIzaSyB17U-TaHiXF-egDyrrCT_kejxz5ckXDNA",
        libraries: ["places"]
    })

    const [map, setMap] = React.useState(null)

    const onLoad = useCallback((map) => (mapRef.current = map), []);

    const onUnmount = React.useCallback(function callback(map) {
        setMap(null)
    }, [])

    ///tamaño mapa
    const containerStyle = {
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%"
    };

    // /centro al cargar mapa (geolocalizacion usuario)


    const center = useMemo<LatLngLiteral>(() => ({ lat: currentLatitude, lng: currentLongitude }), [currentLatitude, currentLongitude])

    console.log('lat:', currentLatitude, 'lng:', currentLongitude)



    ///Activar infoWindow al pulsar marker

    const [activeMarker, setActiveMarker] = useState(null)

    const divStyle = {
        background: `white`,
        border: `1px solid #ccc`,
        padding: 15
    }

    const handleActiveMarker = (marker) => {
        if (marker === activeMarker) {
            return;
        }
        setActiveMarker(marker);
    };


    ///filtrar por clinicas

    const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false);
    const [isChecked2, setIsChecked2] = useState(false);
    const [isChecked3, setIsChecked3] = useState(false);

    const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {

        console.log(isChecked)
        setIsChecked(e.target.checked);
        isChecked === true ? setClinicSearchConcertSelected(-1) :
            setClinicSearchConcertSelected(parseInt(e.target.value))

    };

    const handleChangeMutua = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        console.log(isChecked2)
        setIsChecked2(e.target.checked);
        isChecked2 === true ? setClinicSearchConcertMutuaSelected(-1) :
            setClinicSearchConcertMutuaSelected(parseInt(e.target.value))

    };

    const handleChangeHealt = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        console.log(isChecked3)
        setIsChecked3(e.target.checked);
        isChecked3 === true ? setClinicSearchConcertHealtSelected(-1) :
            setClinicSearchConcertHealtSelected(parseInt(e.target.value))

    };

    const handleChangeFilter = () => {

        var resultSearch = clinicList.filter((element) => {

            var feature: number[] = [];
            if (element.featureFilterList) {
                feature = element.featureFilterList?.split(',').map(x => parseInt(x));
            }
            var isOk =
                (clinicSearchConcertSelected == -1 || feature.includes(clinicSearchConcertSelected)) &&
                (clinicSearchConcertMutuaSelected == -1 || feature.includes(clinicSearchConcertMutuaSelected)) &&
                (clinicSearchConcertHealtSelected == -1 || feature.includes(clinicSearchConcertHealtSelected))
            if (isOk) {
                return element;
            }

        });
        setClinicListFiltered(resultSearch);

    }

    function compareMarker(a,b) {
        if (a.distance < b.distance)
           return -1;
        if (a.distance > b.distance)
          return 1;
        return 0;
      }


    //Función auxiliar, calcula la distancia entre dos puntos por medio de la función de  


    function getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {

        var R = 6371; // radio de la tierraa km
        var dLat = deg2rad(lat2 - lat1);  // deg2rad 
        var dLon = deg2rad(lon2 - lon1);
        var a =
            Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
            Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) *
            Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2)
            ;
        var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
        var d = R * c; // Distancia en km
    
        return d;

    }

    function deg2rad(deg) {
        return deg * (Math.PI / 180)

    }
///funcion ordenar clinicas por distancia

  function orderByDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
      clinicListFiltered.map(clinic =>(
          clinic.distanceClinics = getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(currentLatitude, currentLongitude, clinic.latitude, clinic.longitude)

      ))

      clinicListFiltered.sort()
  }
   

    useEffect(() => {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
            console.log(position)
            setCurrentLatitude(position.coords.latitude)
            setCurrentLongitude(position.coords.longitude)
            fetchClinicList();
            fetchCollections();
        })
    }, []);


    return (
        <>
            <div>
                {showModalLocator ? (
                    <>
                        <div className="justify-center items-center flex overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-auto fixed inset-0 z-50 outline-none focus:outline-none">
                            <div className="relative p-2 w-full max-w-5xl h-full md:h-auto">
                                {/*content*/}
                                <div className="relative top-6 md:top-0 bg-white rounded-lg shadow">
                                    {/*header*/}
                                    <div className="flex justify-between items-start px-4 py-3 rounded-t border-b">
                                        <h3 className="text-lg font-medium">Localizador de clinicas</h3>
                                        <button className="text-gray-400 bg-transparent hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-gray-900 rounded-lg text-sm p-1.5 ml-auto inline-flex items-center" onClick={closeModalLocator}>
                                            <svg aria-hidden="true" className="w-5 h-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                                <path fillRule="evenodd" d="M4.293 4.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 8.586l4.293-4.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L11.414 10l4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L10 11.414l-4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L8.586 10 4.293 5.707a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clipRule="evenodd"></path>
                                            </svg>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    {/*body*/}
                                    <div className="relative px-3 py-3 flex-auto overflow-auto md:overflow-hidden modal-body">
                                        <h2 className="text-sm font-medium mb-2">¿Dónde te encuentras?</h2>
                                        <Places setDirection={(position) => {
                                            setDirection(position);
                                            mapRef.current?.panTo(position);
                                         

                                        }} />

                                        <div className="py-3 border-b flex flex-col md:flex-row items-start md:items-center md:justify-between justify-start gap-2">
                                            <div className="flex items-center">
                                                {clinicSearchConcerts.slice(0, 1).map(fields => (
                                                    <>

                                                        <label key={fields.id} className="inline-flex relative items-center mr-5 cursor-pointer">
                                                            <input
                                                                className="sr-only peer"
                                                                type="checkbox"
                                                                onChange={handleChange}
                                                                value={fields.id}
                                                                checked={isChecked}
                                                            />
                                                            <div className="w-11 h-6 bg-gray-200 rounded-full peer peer-focus:ring-teal-600 
                                                                peer-checked:after:translate-x-full peer-checked:after:border-white after:content-[''] 
                                                                 after:absolute after:top-0.5 after:left-[2px] after:bg-white after:border-gray-300 after:border after:rounded-full after:h-5 after:w-5 after:transition-all peer-checked:bg-teal-600"></div>
                                                            <span className="ml-2 text-xs font-medium text-gray-900">{fields.name}</span>
                                                        </label>

                                                    </>

                                                ))}
                                                {clinicSearchConcerts.slice(1, 2).map(fields => (
                                                    <>

                                                        <label key={fields.id} className="inline-flex relative items-center mr-5 cursor-pointer">
                                                            <input
                                                                className="sr-only peer"
                                                                type="checkbox"
                                                                onChange={handleChangeMutua}
                                                                value={fields.id}
                                                                checked={isChecked2}
                                                            />
                                                            <div className="w-11 h-6 bg-gray-200 rounded-full peer peer-focus:ring-teal-600 
                                                                peer-checked:after:translate-x-full peer-checked:after:border-white after:content-[''] 
                                                                 after:absolute after:top-0.5 after:left-[2px] after:bg-white after:border-gray-300 after:border after:rounded-full after:h-5 after:w-5 after:transition-all peer-checked:bg-teal-600"></div>
                                                            <span className="ml-2 text-xs font-medium text-gray-900">{fields.name}</span>
                                                        </label>

                                                    </>

                                                ))}
                                                {clinicSearchConcerts.slice(2, 3).map(fields => (
                                                    <>

                                                        <label key={fields.id} className="inline-flex relative items-center mr-5 cursor-pointer">
                                                            <input
                                                                className="sr-only peer"
                                                                type="checkbox"
                                                                onChange={handleChangeHealt}
                                                                value={fields.id}
                                                                checked={isChecked3}
                                                            />
                                                            <div className="w-11 h-6 bg-gray-200 rounded-full peer peer-focus:ring-teal-600 
                                                                peer-checked:after:translate-x-full peer-checked:after:border-white after:content-[''] 
                                                                 after:absolute after:top-0.5 after:left-[2px] after:bg-white after:border-gray-300 after:border after:rounded-full after:h-5 after:w-5 after:transition-all peer-checked:bg-teal-600"></div>
                                                            <span className="ml-2 text-xs font-medium text-gray-900">{fields.name}</span>
                                                        </label>

                                                    </>

                                                ))}
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            <h2 className="text-sm font-medium my-3">Resultados</h2>

                                            <div className="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 gap-4">
                                                <div className="w-100 h-40 md:h-96">
                                                    {isLoaded && (
                                                        <GoogleMap
                                                            zoom={15}
                                                            mapContainerStyle={containerStyle}
                                                            center={center}
                                                            onLoad={onLoad}
                                                            onUnmount={onUnmount}
                                                        >
                                                            {console.log('center', center)}
                                                            <MarkerF position={{ lat: currentLatitude, lng: currentLongitude }} />


                                                            {clinicListFiltered.map((clinic) => (

                                                                <React.Fragment key={clinic.id}>
                                                                    {direction && getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(direction.lat, direction.lng, clinic.latitude, clinic.longitude) <= 30 ?

                                                                        <MarkerF position={{ lat: clinic.latitude ? clinic.latitude : -1, lng: clinic.longitude ? clinic.longitude : -1 }} onClick={() => handleActiveMarker(clinic.id)} options={{ icon: iconclinic }}>
                                                                            {activeMarker === clinic.id ? (
                                                                                <InfoWindow
                                                                                    position={{ lat: clinic.latitude ? clinic.latitude : -1, lng: clinic.longitude ? clinic.longitude : -1 }}
                                                                                    onCloseClick={() => setActiveMarker(null)}
                                                                                >
                                                                                    <div style={divStyle}>
                                                                                        <h1>{clinic.title}</h1>
                                                                                        <p>{clinic.address}</p>
                                                                                        <p>{clinic.phone}</p>
                                                                                        <p>{clinic.email}</p>
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                </InfoWindow>
                                                                            ) : null}
                                                                        </MarkerF>
                                                                        : null
                                                                    }
 
                                                                </React.Fragment>

                                                            ))}
                                                            {direction && (
                                                                <MarkerF position={direction} />
                                                            )}
                                                        </GoogleMap>
                                                    )}
                                                </div>
                                                <div className="overflow-auto max-h-96">
                                               

                                                    { !direction ?
                                                       
                                                        clinicListFiltered.map((clinic) =>  (
                                                            <>
                                                            
                                                                <div key={clinic.id} className="card bg-white px-2 py-3 h-62 md:h-50 mb-3">
                                                                    <button type="button" className="text-left">

                                                                        <p>{getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(currentLatitude, currentLongitude, clinic.latitude, clinic.longitude).toFixed()}Km</p>
                                                                        {console.log(getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(currentLatitude, currentLongitude, clinic.latitude, clinic.longitude).toFixed())}

                                                                        <div className="flex items-center gap-2 md:gap-4 md:gap-4">

                                                                            <img className="h-24 w-2/5 min-w-40 object-container object-center rounded-lg" src={contentUtils.getLargeImageUrl(clinic.logo)} alt="#" />
                                                                            <div className="w-3/5">
                                                                                <div className="text-md font-medium leading-5 clinic-title uppercase">{clinic.title}</div>
                                                                                <div className="flex items-currentLatitude, currentLongitude, clinic.latitude, clinic.longitudecenter gap-2">
                                                                                    <div className="text-neutral-500 text-sm">{clinic.propsPhone}</div>
                                                                                    <div className="text-neutral-500 text-sm">{clinic.mobile}</div>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                                <div className="text-teal-600 text-sm underline clinic-mail">{clinic.email}</div>
                                                                                <div className="text-neutral-500 text-xs">{getType(clinic.type)}</div>
                                                                                <div className="text-neutral-500 text-xs">{getPhysiotherapyFields(clinic.physiotherapyFields)}</div>
                                                                                <div className="text-neutral-500 text-xs">{getOthers(clinic.others)}</div>
                                                                                <div className="text-neutral-500 text-xs">{getFeatureFilters(clinic.featureFilterList)}</div>
                                                                                <div className="text-neutral-500 text-sm">{clinic.registry}</div>
                                                                                <div className="text-neutral-500 text-sm">{clinic.distanceClinics}</div>

                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </button>
                                                                </div>
                                                              
                                                            </>
                                                        ))
                                                    :
                                                    
                                                      
                                                            clinicListFiltered.map((clinic) => (                                                                
                                                                getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(direction.lat, direction.lng, clinic.latitude, clinic.longitude) <= 30 ?
                                                            <div key={clinic.id} className="card bg-white px-2 py-3 h-62 md:h-50 mb-3">
                                                                <button type="button" className="text-left">
                                                                    <p>{getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(direction.lat, direction.lng, clinic.latitude, clinic.longitude).toFixed()} Km</p>
                                                                        <div className="flex items-center gap-2 md:gap-4 md:gap-4">
                                                                        <img className="h-24 w-2/5 min-w-40 object-container object-center rounded-lg" src={contentUtils.getLargeImageUrl(clinic.logo)} alt="#" />
                                                                        <div className="w-3/5">
                                                                            <div className="text-md font-medium leading-5 clinic-title uppercase">{clinic.title}</div>
                                                                            <div className="flex items-center gap-2">
                                                                                <div className="text-neutral-500 text-sm">{clinic.propsPhone}</div>
                                                                                <div className="text-neutral-500 text-sm">{clinic.mobile}</div>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                            <div className="text-teal-600 text-sm underline clinic-mail">{clinic.email}</div>
                                                                            <div className="text-neutral-500 text-sm">{clinic.registry}</div>
                                                                            <div className="text-teal-600 text-sm underline clinic-mail">{clinic.email}</div>
                                                                            <div className="text-neutral-500 text-xs">{getType(clinic.type)}</div>
                                                                            <div className="text-neutral-500 text-xs">{getPhysiotherapyFields(clinic.physiotherapyFields)}</div>
                                                                            <div className="text-neutral-500 text-xs">{getOthers(clinic.others)}</div>
                                                                            <div className="text-neutral-500 text-xs">{getFeatureFilters(clinic.featureFilterList)}</div>
                                                                            <div className="text-neutral-500 text-sm">{clinic.registry}</div>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </button>
                                                            </div>
                                                            
                                                            :  null
                                                            ))

                                                                    
                                                        }
                                                    
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    {/*footer*/}
                                    <div className="bg-white flex items-center justify-end px-4 py-2 border-t border-solid border-slate-200 rounded-b gap-2">
                                        <button className="btn text-black text-sm background-transparent px-8 outline-none focus:outline-none focus:ring-teal-600 focus:border-teal-600" type="button" onClick={closeModalLocator}>Cancelar</button>
                                        <button className="bg-teal-600 hover:bg-teal-700 text-white text-sm active:bg-teal-700 px-8 py-2 outline-none focus:outline-none rounded" type="button" onClick={handleChangeFilter}>Buscar</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="opacity-25 fixed inset-0 z-40 bg-black"></div>
                    </>
                ) : null}

            </div>

        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [como ordenar las clinicas por distancia?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/566694/como-ordenar-las-clinicas-por-distancia)

Comment: se que tengo que ordenar las distancias antes de pasar la lista, lo que no se como